# How to edit Sidebar under Sphinx Alabaster theme

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar, restructuredtext, toctree

I have the following `index.rst` file.

```
Know the cell population of your data
=====================================
Some content

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

Installation
~~~~~~~~~~~~
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   installation

Scripts
~~~~~~~
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   scripts

API documentation
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   apidoc

Roadmap
~~~~~~~
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   roadmap

Indices and Tables
==================
* :ref: `genindex`
```

Now the sidebar looks like this:

[image]

As described in that image. I'd like to do couple of things.

1. remove the title *only* in the sidebar but maintaining it in the main page.
2. add new URL link, but not showing it in the main page like "Indices and Tables"

How can I do that?

Comment: The [documentation](http://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html) for alabaster describes how to overcome these problems now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally fixed it the following way

In the Sphinx's **_template** directory create a file
called `foo.html`.

The content may look something like this:

```
<hr />
<p>
<h2 class='logo'>
<a href="https://foo.bar.com/">Web Version</a>
</h2>
</p>
```

Finally in **conf.py** add this:

```
html_sidebars = {
        '**': [
                 'localtoc.html',
                 'relations.html',
                 'searchbox.html',
                 # located at _templates/
                 'foo.html',
            ]

        }
```

At the end it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There's a typo here; the 2nd sentence should say `_templates` with an 's'.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose something for the first question. I'm in no way an expert in CSS so my solution isn't probably the more elegant one, but it works ! Put in your 'source/_static/custom.css' file :

```
.sphinxsidebar a.reference.internal[href='#'] {
  display: none;
}
```

Maybe a CSS expert should give a better selector …